# Convert ABRecord to NSString*

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to convert ABRecord to string

`textfield.text=(NSString *)(ABRecordGetRecordID(ref));`

how can i do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ABRecordID is just a type def for:

```
NSInteger recordID  =  ABRecordGetRecordID(ref);
textfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", recordID];
```

Comment: and kindly tell me does ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i ); gives me list of all of my contacts, i actually want to maintain a database of all my phone contacts :)